# How do i send the data in my javascript query to mysql database by a push of a button?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm very new to databases and mysql, but i have to know how i update my database from a pre-written javascript query. Until now i have done it manually over the terminal in javascript with: **node main.js**. This works just fine but i want to do this with a button.

```
const { createPool } = require('mysql')
const pool = createPool({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  connectionLimit: 10,
})

pool.query(`
    insert into test.users(first_name, last_name, email)
    values('${fname.value}', '${lname.value}', '${email.value}')
    `)
```

Thank you in advance.

I could not try very much because i didn't find much and all the tutorials i watched on youtube were not helpful at all.

Comment: Step 1: Figure out how you are going to draw the button. Are you going to use a windowing library to draw a classic GUI? Are you going to use something along the lines of ncurses to draw a console based GUI? Are you going to write a web app and have the button in a web browser client? Are you going to use something like Electron?

Comment: You need some kind of user interface like a website, mobile, or desktop app. Note that you can not interact with your database from the client because of security reasons. Therefore you need to provide an API by your backend (e.g. CRUD app). So when you click the button, this will call your backend which then talks to your database

Comment: @marcobiedermann — What client? I listed 3 approaches to drawing the GUI that didn't use a client-server model in my previous comment.